# how to get timezones or dates from major world clock websites by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

i know that we have an object in JavaScript ( Date(); ) that give us the date . this object give us our PC date . that is good BUT you think that our pc's date is not set correctly and this object ( Date(); ) give us wrong date .

i want to know that can we get date from major world clock websites or timezones or a clock server to show the exact date always even our pc's clock is not set correct ? for example get time or date from timeanddate.com or 24timezones.com or another clock servers ...

if YES, HOW ?
tnx for your attetion ...

Comment: i recommend you to use moment.js http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Date() is not an object; "major clock website" I assume you mean NTP server

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil, does moment.js use an external resource for time?

Comment: yes you can use UTC features

Comment: Any times generated by moment.js will be just as inaccurate as using the built in `Date` object.  The OP is asking for a way to get a known, accurate time from a server.

Comment: If you trust you server's clock then you can use it. Are you using PHP/ASP.net/something?

Comment: You can use the `Date` object too.  You can't use moment.js to get an accurate date, you have to use some other mechanism to retrieve it from your trusted server, then initialise either one of them with it.

Comment: Try http://james.padolsey.com/snippets/getting-the-real-time-in-javascript/

Comment: no but i wanted to use major clock websites that you offer me momentjs.com ...

Comment: To use an ntp server you'll need to implement ntp client. However I am not sure if thats possible as ntp proticol requires you to send packets over UDP , and I think your ordinary website js just cant do that. You should try to approach to this task from server side

Answer (score 3):

Use this on your HTML head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json?callback=myCallback"></script>
```

then use this js code in `<scripts>`

```
function myCallback(json) {
    alert(new Date(json.dateString));
}
```

to get UTC time use this

```
function myCallback(json) {
    var utcDate = new Date(json.dateString);
    alert(utcDate.getUTCFullYear() + '/' + utcDate.getUTCMonth() + '/' + utcDAte.getUTCDate());
}
```

It will give you correct time all the time

Comment: i used your code but my browser cant connect to timeapi.org . because of this, cant run the code . what should i do ?

Comment: did you changed to [http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json?callback=myCallback](http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json?callback=myCallback)? i mean did you added www before it

Comment: just paste that url in your browser.. and you should get this `myCallback({"dateString":"July 10, 2015 13:02:32 GMT+0100"});` then it must work

Comment: everything i do doesnt work . excuse me may copy your complete code here to compare with my code to notice why doesnt work ?

Comment: [http://jsbin.com/tejafofune/edit?html,output](http://jsbin.com/tejafofune/edit?html,output) here is demo. if it works accept my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82957/discussion-between-mostafa-eslami-and-prabhu-vignesh-rajagopal).